# Generating bitmaps in C++

Tags: c++, bitmap

I am trying to generate an image as the output of a project written in C++. Since bitmap images are very simple compared to most other image formats, I figured that I should try to create a bitmap. I can't use any libraries that which don't come with g++. I want to generate the image from scratch.

The dimensions of the image will be pre-defined. The only input is going to be the value for each pixel.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define w_in_pix 2
#define h_in_pix 4
short padding = 0x0000;
short BM = 0x4d42;

struct bmp_header
{

int size_of_file;
int reserve;
int offset_of_pixle_data;
int size_of_header;
int width;
int hight;
short num_of_colour_plane;
short num_of_bit_per_pix;
int compression;
int size_of_pix_data;
int h_resolution;
int v_resolution;
int num_of_colour_in_palette;
int important_colours;

}
HEADER;

// pix array ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// L to R //
int BGR [24] = {
0xFF,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0xFF,0x00,
0xFF,0x00,0x00, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
0xFF,0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
HEADER.size_of_file = sizeof(HEADER) + sizeof(BGR) + sizeof(padding) * h_in_pix + 2;
    cout << HEADER.size_of_file;
HEADER.reserve = 0000;
HEADER.offset_of_pixle_data = 54;
HEADER.size_of_header = 40;
HEADER.width = w_in_pix;
HEADER.hight = h_in_pix;
HEADER.num_of_colour_plane = 1;
HEADER.num_of_bit_per_pix = 24;
HEADER.compression = 0;
HEADER.size_of_pix_data = sizeof(BGR) + sizeof(padding) * h_in_pix;
HEADER.h_resolution = 2835;
HEADER.v_resolution = 2835;
HEADER.num_of_colour_in_palette = 0;
HEADER.important_colours = 0;

// write BMP Header ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ofstream file;
file.open ("test.bmp", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
file.write ((char*)(&BM), 2);
file.write ((char*)(&HEADER), sizeof(HEADER));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// write BMP data //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//file.write ((char*)(&BGR[0]),1);


int position = w_in_pix * h_in_pix * 3;
while (position != 0)
{
for (int n = 0; n != w_in_pix * 3; n++)
{
file.write ((char*)(&BGR[position - w_in_pix * 3 + n]), 1);
}
file.write ((char*)(&padding), 2);
position = position - w_in_pix * 3;
}


}
```

I started with some code I found online and have been tweaking it, but I have run into two problems.

1. I can only change the vertical height of the image.  If I change the width, the outputted image is corrupted.  I think this has to do with size calculation.
2. I am not sure about how I can feed each pixel's color data in one at a time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: BMP works through the concept of stride. Each line (row) is a stride, that may contains more bytes than the actual number of pixel. To calculate the stride use the formula ((width * bitperpixel) + 7) / 8

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  What do you mean by moving pixels and how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Well done for making and showing the attempt, and identifying specific issues. You should indent your code, though.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a bitmap is not exactly so simple, there are several kind of BMP files.

You should respect microsoft specification about BMP, and following them for all possible formats can be quite annoying.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap

Your error, i guess, is that each row has a specific size that may contains padding for memory alignment, see the wikipedia image at the link above.

Each row (call it stride) have a specific size of ((width * bitperpixel) + 7) / 8 bytes.

In your code, you can try to check the line

```
file.write ((char*)(&padding), 2);
```

Instead, you need to write there `(((w_in_pix * 24) + 7) / 8) - (w_in_pix * 3)` empty bytes
I hope I did the right calculations :)

I would suggest, if you can, to use an open source library instead, will save u a lot of headaches.

Searching on google i just found http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/ this library seems very small, just 5 files that you can include in your project.
Very simple to use and it seems good for what you want to do.